# Data Rendering - Query The Database

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using datatables and have a strange situation.

I have come to the conclusion I need to manipulate my data through the render, however I am not sure where or how to go about it. I am looking for a bit of direction because I cant seem to find a manual of any sorts. Java is not my strong point.

I have data coming through Server Side Processing as this:

`{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[["ATS20151209_78983","2|6|8|4","1","12-09-15","CM20151020_999999999","Curabitur egestas nunc nisl, sit amet feugiat erat tincidunt eu. Praesent consequat blandit venenatis. Pellentesque habitant mor"],["ATS20151209_78984","2|8","3","12-09-15","CM20151020_999999998",""]]}`

There are two pieces of data I want to change before they are displayed. The first is an array of unknown size (In the above example give as 2|6|8|4 & 2|8). I want to query a table in my database that has the corresponds to the text values. Same thing with the second value except this time there is no array shown as 1 & 3 above.

I am not looking for anyone to write the code but a little direction is nice since the documentation is covering so much. I don't even know what I should be calling this or looking up.

Thank you.

Comment: what kind of change would you do in the data.

Comment: It seems you are looking for something like Column Render in datatables. if this is the case [Follow This Link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html) for example.

Comment: I know I am looking for Rendering but I am not sure how to take the data and query the database in javascript.